# Reflection alternative for performance

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, system.reflection

I am implementing a Data Access Layer for a project using plain Dapper. I am using both a generic repository for CRUD operations and a generic query builder for my queries.

My problem arises when annotating properties and accessing annotations in query builder. I have used entity framework before and although it is really good at abstracting but it has performance bottlenecks which this project might not be a good fit for.

My model is like this:-

```
    [ModelAttributes(Key = "CubeID")]
    public class RepSysCube
    {
        public int CubeID { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
        public int AuthorisationID { get; set; }
        public string CubeName { get; set; }
        public string CubeDescription { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
```

ModelAttribute is something like this:-

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    internal class ModelAttributes : System.Attribute
    {
        private string _Key;
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return _Key;
            }
            set
            {
                _Key = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Repository is something like this :-

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        string query = queryBuilder.SelectByID(id);
        var queryResult = dbConnection.Query<T>(query);
        return queryResult.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Now to generate my queries I can use something like this :-

```
internal class QueryBuilder<T> : IQueryBuilder<T> where T : class
{
    string _Query = string.Empty;
    public string SelectByID(int ID)
    {
        _Query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1} = '{2}'", typeof(T).Name, ((ModelAttributes)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(x => x == (ModelAttributes)x).First()).Key, ID);
        return _Query;
    }
}
```

My problem is to use

```
((ModelAttributes)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(x => x == (ModelAttributes)x).First()).Key
```

I know that Reflection in C# has performance cost. Is there any other other way where i can achieve something similar to this where I can easily determine characteristics of a Model class.

I tried using a function inside the Model class but much to my dismay, I couldn't call the function using T.

Comment: You could use `System.Linq.Expressions`

Comment: Thank you @BercoviciAdrian . Any additional help on how to use this in this scenario would help me reach there faster. I have already spent hours looking for alternatives.

Comment: "I know that Reflection in C# has performance cost" Yes and no. Will those costs be **remarkable** in your application? Did you **measure** if you have issues caused by this code? Otherwise you may end up overcomplicating your code for the sake of some nano-seconds.

Comment: I don't have measures yet but I know Reflection has performance cost. And during this early stage of the project, it might get to a point where it poses performace issues. This application needs to run on the cloud with a few hundred users which might also increase. @HimBromBeere

Comment: "I know Reflection has performance cost" That depends on how you define costs. Generelly **every** line of code has some costs. The question is: which of them are **noticable**. It won´t help you much if you can safe some nano-seconds when your actual **bottleneck** is the network-speed for instance, or the database (**very** common btw.). So you *may* use expression-tree, however this may overcomplicate your logic for nothing.

Comment: Anyway an easy way might be to simply cache the attributes returned by `GetCustomAttributes` somewhere.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just cached the "Key" itself without overcomplicating things, but your advise to cache "GetCustomAttributes" seems better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My usual trick here is to use some `static class SomeCache<T>` and do the work in the static constructor `SomeCache<T>` **per T**. Then `QueryBuilder<T>` just asks `Foo<T>` for the data, and it will be readily available...

Answer (score 0):

Because generic static variables different by type, i.e. `QueryBuilder<Car>.KeyField` is a different variable than `QueryBuilder<Truck>.KeyField` you can execute the reflection only once and just use the variable value for subsequent calls, removing the expense (significant or not) of calling reflection with each call to the method.

```
internal class QueryBuilder<T> : IQueryBuilder<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly string KeyField = ((ModelAttributes)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(x => x == (ModelAttributes)x).First()).Key;
    private string _Query = string.Empty;
    public string SelectByID(int ID)
    {
        // don't create your query this way.  use a parameterized query
        _Query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1} = '{2}'", typeof(T).Name, KeyField, ID);
        return _Query;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used something like this and it works for me. But is there a way where I can move this KeyField declaration into my Model Class itself and then call it by using <T>, that way I wont have to use reflection at all.